# Why does keyof return a different result in this example

Tags: typescript

```
type NodeA = {
  type: 'A'
  name: string
  flag: number
}

type NodeB = {
  type: 'B'
  id: number
  flag: number
}
type Nodes = NodeA | NodeB
```

---

```
type test = {
  [P in keyof Nodes]: 21
}
// it return this
type test = {
    type: 21;
    flag: 21;
}
```

---

But when I use the generic,the results are completely different

```
type test<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: 21
}
type test2 = test<Nodes>
```

test2 return like this type test2 = test | test

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=15&pln=25&pc=20#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgQSgXigbwFBSqSALigHJkTcoA7AQwFsJiBnYAJwEsqBzSgMwBsaXYlQCudAEYRW2AL7ZsBaPCQAhdFkpLiJVRTzsEI8VJl4BQ45OlzF4ZYghMNKlFAA%20sR6oVKovODgAHgAVAD4NHDwAbQAFKE4oAGsIEDheKBCAXR0AuAp5PzyAJg08oNcmMIUAYzgqFigJGlZCEsite0ISPJIAGj5BYR7Agt97f0CAZg6Y%20MSUtIzKnNJe22w6huAmluK26dn8LpH8gfMh7vX5bCA)

Comment: The second piece of code seems to act identical to the first: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgQSgXigbwFBSqSALigHJkTcoA7AQwFsJiBnYAJwEsqBzSgMwBsaXYlQCudAEYRW2AL7ZsBaPCQAhdFkpLiJVRTzsEI8VJl4BQ45OlzF4ZYghMNKlFAA+sR6oVL8T4AAeABUAPg0cPABtAAUoTigAawgQOF4oYIBdYgAmAEZbP2AAnI1ilkDXJlCFJABjQVZoOrgqFiheODhicuAcgG4FTrgAOiV+qAB6SagAeQBpbGGRiy4J6bnF5doGdZnpVjgZZcMJvA2Do6A)

Comment: @VLAZ - It's a bit hard to follow above, but I think they mean [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgQSgXigbwLACgpSiQBcUA5MmXgQHYCGAthKQM7ABOAljQObVQAzADZ0epGgFcGAIwjs8AXzx4i0eEgBC6LP1WkyGqviicE4qbPnHho8zLmKV4NYggtt6lFAA+sVxqdIQjdgVAwcYwBtAAUTGigAawgQOAE-JBYAXVIAJgBGR1xVYLY87WAQ5ABuPABjOBo2QjzSCtLtCIICGzEofIAafgI9PrzB3AUa3EDoNuANAB4AFQA+Dv4YuMTk1Kgl7NHC4rmc8pDFzxYVuoam4BzWkNPwocERXoHXkc+JqaA). Seems like it has to do with the generic distributing the union while the non-generic doesn't...? But it's really not clear.

Comment: @​TonyUndefined - Can you clarify your question, saying specifically what behavior you're seeing that you're having trouble understanding, and ideally provide a link to the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) showing both behaviors? Thanks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder perhaps that's what OP meant. But...then it's hardly a mystery. It's just a type union thing: `A | B` (situation 2) is not satisfied with just the overlapping cross section of both. While in the fist case it's only the cross section which is mapped.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder -[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgQSgXigbwFBSqSALigHJkTcoA7AQwFsJiBnYAJwEsqBzSgMwBsaXYlQCudAEYRW2AL7ZsBaPCQAhdFkpLiJVRTzsEI8VJl4BQ45OlzF4ZYghMNKlFAA+sR6oVKovODgAHgAVAD4NHDwAbQAFKE4oAGsIEDheKBCAXR0AuAp5PzyAJg08oNcmMIUAYzgqFigJGlZCEsite0ISPJIAGj5BYR7Agt97f0CAZg6Y+MSUtIzKnNJe22w6huAmluK26dn8LpH8gfMh7vX5bCA)  I've added  playground link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People are somewhat aware of the fact that some conditional types [distribute over unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), but what is even less documented is that mapped type are also distributive in certain scenarios.

When you use `Nodes` directly there is no distribution. So we have

```
type foo3 = {
  [P in keyof Nodes]: 'foo'
}
// foo3 is equivalent to 
// type foo3 = {
//     type: "foo";
//     flag: "foo";
// }
```

This is beacuse `keyof Nodes` will only result in the common properties of the union so we get a type that only contains properties that are present in both union constituents.

When you have a mapped type that maps over `keyof T`, if `T` is a type parameter that is instantiated with a union, then we get the distributive behavior of mapped types. This means the mapped typed is applied to each constituent of the union and then the results are unioned to form the final result. So we basically have `foo<Nodes> = foo<NodeA | NodeB> = foo<NodeA> | foo<NodeB>`.

This behavior makes sense for a lot of types and is usually pretty intuitive. `Readonly<T>` which is a mapped type is distributive so if you apply to a union, you get a readonly union, not a mangled mess of just the common properties.

You can make a simple type distributive by introducing a type parameter  using a conditional type:

```
// Distributive 
type foo3 = Nodes extends infer T ? {
//    ^?
  [P in keyof T]: 'foo'
}: never
```

You can also avoid distribution by mapping over something other than `keyof T` :

```
// Non distributive
type foo<T> = {
  [P in Exclude<keyof T, never>]: 'foo'
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gEwgQSgXigbwFBSqSALigHJkTcoA7AQwFsJiBnYAJwEsqBzSgMwBsaXYlQCudAEYRW2AL7ZsBaPCQAhdFkpLiJVRTzsEI8VJl4BQ45OlzF4ZYghMNKlFAA+sR6oVKovODgAHgAVAD4NHDwAbQAFKE4oAFEADwBjflEkIIBrCBA4XigQgBpqCAA3aTCAXR0AuAp5PwaAJg0GoNcmMIU0uCoWKAkaVkI2yK17QhIGkhK+QWFZwKbfe39AgGYXR2cIFOAIKgRnTl5pYqgAfk0Aeju8PAA9a8o4hKooPIKikLrSHM5CJKjZsA98BsGjsMDgIU9IUQoAAiBrIgDc4MeCIswhRaMxEPk2H6g2Aw1GrXG20meG0K0aC3MSxmQOJQA)